# Why Doesnt this Simple Modification (to working code) for Making a 5 second timer work?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a simple  C# program (I am using Visual studio 2010) -simply a button on a form-as shown in the link at the very bottom below-that
when this button is pressed it shows the time passing every second in a message box.

This is no mistake in this program its given below and fully working.
It works by setting the variable **starttodisplaytimeronscreen** to true once the button is pressed-this is a flag-and once its set to
true it makes it possible to show the message box to be shown every second.
Here is the working code (that the complete program I am using)

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace finitetimerprogram
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 int thetimeinsecs = 0;// is the number of seconds as an integer that have elapsed since button pressed
  bool starttodisplaytimeronscreen = false;// this is a flag that set to true if button is pressed
  System.Timers.Timer mytimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

  private void customfn(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
      if (starttodisplaytimeronscreen == true)
   {  // starttodisplaytimeronscreen becomes true if the button is clicked
                thetimeinsecs = thetimeinsecs + 1;
  MessageBox.Show("seconds since  pressed= " + thetimeinsecs.ToString(), "seconds since pressed= " + thetimeinsecs.ToString());
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {  // this function is called continually from since when the form is shown onscreen
            InitializeComponent();
            mytimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(customfn);
            mytimer.Interval = 1000;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            starttodisplaytimeronscreen = true;
            mytimer.Start();
        }


    }
}
```

Now I want to modify this program so it stops showing the timer after 5 seconds-
in other words the button click activates a 5 second timer which is shown to
on screen as five message boxes that show the seconds 1,2,3,4 and 5.
Then once the timer stops if the user presses the button again (and again) it starts the 5 second timer again (it is assumed in this situation the button is clicked only once for every time the user want to create a 5 second timer).

Ive done this by adding the simple code

```
  if (thetimeinsecs > 5)
 {// this if statement stop the timer after 5 seconds but doesnt work
  starttodisplaytimeronscreen = false;// supposed to stop displaying the message box after 5 secods
  thetimeinsecs = 0;
   mytimer.Stop();
        }
```

which resets the timer after 5 seconds, resets the flag **starttodisplaytimeronscreen**  to false. Resets **thetimeinsecs** back to zero, and stops the timer with  mytimer.Stop(). 
The problem I am having is such a simple code to modify the working code (initially given above) to make a 5 second timer doesnt work. So my question is why doesnt it work? -and whats an easy way to fix it?

Here below is the complete non working code - just to be clear.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace finitetimerprogram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       int thetimeinsecs = 0;// is the number of seconds as an integer that have elapsed since button pressed
        bool starttodisplaytimeronscreen = false;// this is a flag that set to true if button is pressed
        System.Timers.Timer mytimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        private void customfn(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (starttodisplaytimeronscreen == true)
            {  // starttodisplaytimeronscreen becomes true if the button is clicked
                thetimeinsecs = thetimeinsecs + 1;
                MessageBox.Show("seconds since  pressed= " + thetimeinsecs.ToString(), "seconds since pressed= " + thetimeinsecs.ToString());   
            }


            if (thetimeinsecs > 5)
            {// this if statment stop the timer after 5 seconds but doesnt work
                starttodisplaytimeronscreen = false;// supposed to stop displaying the message box after 5 secods
                thetimeinsecs = 0;
                mytimer.Stop();
            }

        }

        public Form1()
        {  // this function is called continually from since when the form is shown onscreen
            InitializeComponent();
            mytimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(customfn);
            mytimer.Interval = 1000;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            starttodisplaytimeronscreen = true;
            mytimer.Start();
        }
```

[shows what happens after 6 seconds since the button was pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkR4T.jpg)

Comment: You don't have to do this much experiment. Don't start/stop your `mytimer.Start()` everytime.. Start your Timer just once. You better change the `myTimer.Interval = anyvalue` only.

Comment: At first glance your two code examples look the same, and both contain the section of code you claim to be adding. Of course, it's hard to read the code, because you have put so much white-space, it's hard to see very much of it at a time. Please reduce your code to a _single_ example that shows what you've tried, explain precisely but succinctly what the code does, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I must have copied and pasted the same code into the question by accident. So I fixed it . First part gives unmodified code that works. Second part is with the modified code. I think its clearer with two programs-one that works and one with the modification

Comment: I disagree. And you still didn't remove the extra blank lines. But, whatever. More to the point, do you dismiss the message box each time it's displayed? Because if not, the code you're talking about won't execute.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I didnt dismiss the message box before-but if the messsage box is dismissed- in time-every second then my code does work-so the answer to the question is something to do with that. The modified code as given in the question does run and show the message box-but it shows the seconds past 5 seconds if the message box isnt dismissed

Comment: @PeterDuniho but I dont want to dismiss it every second-just want it to stop showing the message box automatically without users dismissal

Comment: @PeterDuniho the question is still unanswered. and i removed some of the blank lines

Comment: _"so the answer to the question is something to do with that"_ -- of course it does. It is _exactly_ that, just as I said. The code you added can't execute until the message box is dismissed. Frankly, I think the answer that was posted below should address the question you've expressed so far. If you want something different, you're not being clear enough about what that is. You wrote above _"but I dont want to dismiss it every second-just want it to stop showing the message box automatically"_ and that's exactly what the posted answer should accomplish.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the answer was changed since last time I saw it- see my comments

Comment: _"the answer was changed since last time I saw it"_ -- not in a material way. The original post showed the correct, useful ordering of the code to achieve what _seems_ to be your goal. The only effect of the edit was to stop the timer after 5 seconds instead of 6 as originally posted. It would take only _literally_ one more second to see that the timer did in fact stop. You'll have more success receiving help if you engage yourself in the process and actually make an effort to understand what the answer says, instead of jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "the answer was changed since last time I saw it" - it changed enough to make my precise and logical brain believe it was incorrect because when it went to 6 before I thought it would go on past 5 forever. Add to that the intervals between the boxes (for some unknown reason) on my PC seemed uneven to me like it was a little more than a second for some of the intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix could be by swapping lines your function as shown below:

```
private void customfn(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (thetimeinsecs >= 5)
    {// this if statment stop the timer after 5 seconds but doesnt work
        starttodisplaytimeronscreen = false;// supposed to stop displaying the message box after 5 secods
        thetimeinsecs = 0;
        mytimer.Stop();
    }

    if (starttodisplaytimeronscreen == true)
    {  // starttodisplaytimeronscreen becomes true if the button is clicked
        thetimeinsecs = thetimeinsecs + 1;
        MessageBox.Show("seconds since  pressed= " + thetimeinsecs.ToString(), "seconds since pressed= " + thetimeinsecs.ToString());
    }

}
```

If you want to improve it further than you can get rid of `starttodisplaytimeronscreen` with slight change in logic. I'll leave that for you.

Comment: I tried this and this isnt the answer -so your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Following on from a comment above its related to dismissing the message box as soon as it appears -then the code works -but I dont want to dismiss it every second-just want it to stop showing the message box automatically without users dismissal

Comment: the question is still unanswered

Comment: @user43655672 Please specify what you want at end of 5 seconds. Do you want all 5 message boxes to be still shown but timer to stop? And if user clicks on button then again 5 messages boxes will be shown and then timer stops. Please confirm.

Comment: the program beahaves the way I want when the message box are dismissed. Just run the program and see

Comment: @user43655672 I'm running the program at my end with modified code. It displays 5 message boxes and time stops. Click again on button and it will display 5 more message boxes before timer stops. No need to clear message boxes. Please use the modified code.

Comment: The confusion to me of if your answer is correct is you just changed the condition thetimeinsecs >= 5 from thetimeinsecs >5 (which was the condition when I first saw it and this older condition make it go up to 6 seconds-so I mistakenly though it would keep going). So the new version of your answer is correct.

Comment: ADDING an IMPORTANT fact to your answer a point of confusion for me was that the message box not being dismissed stops code after it being executed

Comment: Why this fact is true in C# im not sure. For this is not always true for languages used to develop windows application- e.g. unmanaged C++,  and made me confused

Comment: @user43655672: There is nothing about C# that is different in a way that would explain your confusion. Unmanaged C++ would still require you to dismiss a dialog before the code proceeds, i.e. calling the `DialogBox()` function. In fact, Winforms in C# is just a thin layer over the native API. If you really understood the native API, you'd understand .NET Winforms too.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I wrote e.g. C++ in other words it was an example of a language.It would have been more accurate for me to write I have used languages where there is a message box type function (so that means not precisely a message box) that when used doesnt stop the flow of execution of code.